# Make a div adapt to rotated children size with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a rotated div contained inside a box, and want the outside div to contain the rotated children exactly. Here's an example:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"/>
</div>
```

```css
.box {
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}

.container{
  margin: 3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid black;
  // padding: 19px;
}
```

This looks like this:

[image]

Adding the padding (commented above), I can approximate the result I want, which is this:

[image]

The problem is that it is not exact, and it is hard-coded instead of automatic.

Comment: You'd need JS to do that ....and a bunch of math/

Comment: always the same angle?

Comment: I wanted a solution that worked no matter the angle, and even for multiple divs. The real world use case is a triangle arrow made with 2 rotated divs, which is off-center and I wanted to correct the box.

Answer (score 2):

For `45deg` it's easy

```css
.box {
  --size: 100px; /* the size to define width,height and margin*/
  
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: calc(0.207*var(--size));
  /* 0.2071 = sin(45deg) - 1/2 */
}

.container {
  margin: 3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So the only real way of making it work with any angle would be to calculate the sin in js and provide it to css, and make a bunch of math. Thanks for this! It might be too complex for the value the thing I'm doing provides, but I'll keep it in mind.